# Munin stopped sending email alerts

Tags: email, munin

To check whether Munin email notifications are still functioning, I have changed temporarily the "warning" and "critical" threshold to a very low value, and restarted the munin-node service.

To my dismay, I did not receive any Munin alert.

The Postfix service is running on port 25 and I can easily connect via telnet to it.  I can send mail from command line -- and receive it correctly on my remote mailbox.  `/var/log/maillog` contains references to the messages I sent from command line but nothing from Munin, so it appears that Munin is not sending any alert.

Is there any log that I could peruse to see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem went away by itself after I reinstalled the `ssmtp` package.

I also modified the following line in `/etc/munin/munin.conf` so to include the full path to the `mail` binary:

```
contact.example.command /bin/mail -s "Munin alert" me@example.com
```